# The server is busy now.Try again later sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2015

I am having above error when 1000 users access my SharePoint at a time. I checked LOGS and found that connections pools limit exceeded.

I searched on internet but could not found reasonable answers.

I am testing my site using Visual Studio by access site page with 1000 users on constant load.

I want to know what objects creates SQL connection and to know which objects are not being closed properly?

Do I have to increase some throttling values ?

Note. I have 3 WFE 2 APP Servers and one DATABASE

Comment: What specifications are the servers that are running SharePoint? Can you increase the amount of RAM allocated to each server?

Comment: right now if 24 GB ram on each WFE with 2.1 Ghz processor with 15 processors and these are VMs

Comment: can you tell me how much RAM and processor is required for 5000 concurrent users ?

Comment: I would expect that 4 CPU cores with 24Gb RAM should be fine, however it depends a little on exactly what roles each server is performing. Have you monitored what happens to the server at the time you see the error message? You'll want to monitor RAM, CPU and disk usage on the SharePoint servers and on the SQL Server(s) to see where the issue may be occurring.

Comment: Ram Stays normal, only CPU usage went to 100%

Comment: Sometimes I get error Connection pool limit exceeded

Comment: Can you check in the health analyser page in Central Administration to see what is being reported. Are you seeing "Application pools recycle when memory limits are exceeded"? If so, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh407293.aspx for a resolution.

Comment: I don't see this error, Can you please tell me what sharePoint object create SQL connection ? I want close these type of objects as soon as possible

Comment: Pretty much everything in SharePoint makes a SQL connection!

Comment: Do you find any solution?